# get the file path in web project when running unit test project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-io, c#-3.0

Actually im getting error when the below code is executed from unit test project...
where import is an xml file in the below code..

```
XmlTextReader importReader= new XmlTextReader(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Importcontent/import"));
```

the above code is present in one of the methods in different project(class library) which is used in test method in the unit test project

where as the above path is present in web project.
and the value of the

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Importcontent/import")
```

is null..ie unable to get the complete path of the file i guess bcos the hostingenvironment is not running(web project)
The above code is working fine when running from the webproject ie it returns the exact path.
whereas returning null value when running from test project.

please let me know how to fetch the file path(where file is present in web project) when running from test project.

Comment: This is a valid question.  The answer wants you to work around it.  Ever find a solution?

Comment: @shiv455 I am also looking for similar solution. Have you found any answer to this issue ? Other than moving file name to Controller which i also really don't want to do

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the filename as argument to the method instead of having the method attempting to retrieve it:

```
public void SomeMethod(string filename)
{
    using (XmlTextReader importReader = new XmlTextReader(filename))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now when calling this method from your web tier (a controller) you could pass the filename like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Importcontent/import");
    SomeMethod(filename);
    ...
}
```

and when inside the test project you could pass some other file that you have deployed with your unit test.

Comment: actually we are running only the test project right i guess controller will not be there in the this context....please correct if im wrong.. Actually in brief i want the path of the file which is present in web project which is not running...when we ran the test project

Comment: In the unit test you will be unit testing only the method in question in isolation. There won't be any controller.

Comment: yeah but the method s not present in any controller its present in other class library project..

Comment: And what's the problem with that? In order to unit test it, you create an instance of the class containing this method (unless it is static) and you invoke the method. And you do exactly the same thing in your web tier.

Comment: actually i didnt get why do you need to make changes in web tier as the problem is in unit test..correct me if im wrong

Comment: It's because the method now takes an argument which represents the filename. So you need to change the way you are calling it.

Comment: but actually the code which u mentioned ie                     string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Importcontent/import"); is not in any controller its in someother class library project..where in the method which has this code is called from unit test project.

Comment: @user1065358, I think you are missing the whole point of my answer. The idea is exactly to move this Server.MapPath code into your controller and have your class library method take the filename as argument.

Comment: thanks for ur input but i cannot move that method to controller as it has other major logic.

Comment: Then I am afraid that you will not be able to unit test your method in isolation because HostingEnvironment.MapPath works only within an HttpContext.

Comment: can we use any other code snippet instead of using HostingEnvironment.MapPath to get the path of the file which is in web project...

Comment: This is the correct method to use. It's just that you are not using it at the right place.